# How can I make the terminal type a character 1 by 1 in ruby?

Tags: ruby, terminal

First here an example of what I am talking about. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KXzNo0vR_dU  You see how in the first 2 seconds the Computer is typing out the sentence letter by letter on the same line. I want the program to do that. So if i say    puts "Hello, I am cool" I want it to type the sentence out letter by letter with a small delay in the Ruby programing language. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is:

- Print one character
- Print `|` (to simulate the cursor)
- Sleep a little
- Print a backspace (`\b`) to delete the cursor
- Continue with the next character

  ```
  'GREETINGS PROFESSOR FALKEN.'.each_char do |char|
    print "#{char}|"
    sleep 0.1
    print "\b"
  end
  ```

You can adjust the delay to your preferred speed.

Also you could replace `|` with `█` if it looks cooler to you that way.

Comment: Ah, when not overwriting the string, one doesn't need to flush stdout.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, flushing stdout? What do you mean? I'm just deleting the cursor (`|`).

Comment: yeah, I was referring to a previous version of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. You just print a char, then sleep for a bit. Something like this should work

```
def print_slowly(str)
  str.chars.each do |c|
    print c
    sleep(0.05)
  end
end

print_slowly 'hello, I am cool'
```